# How to get the progress of soaplib exposed function?

Tags: python, multithreading, suds, soaplib

I'm using `soaplib` as wsgi application and `suds` as soap client,

My Question is when client is requesting to execute RPC I want to keep the function in background and server should return some unique id from which client may call a process  like `get_progress` and which will communicate with the thread and return the percentage of progress of a longgg function.

I need any hint or implementation hook, idea how can I integrate it.